# WebRTC stuck in connecting state

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I have successfully communicated the offer, answer and ice candidates for a WebRTC connection from A to B. At this point, the connection is stuck in the `"connecting"` state. The initiator (A) seems to timeout or something after a while and switch to the `"failed"` state, whereas its remote (B) is staying in the `"connecting"` state permanently.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Creation of peer (A and B):

```
let peer = new RTCPeerConnection({
    iceServers: [
        {
            urls: [
                "stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302",
                "stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302",
            ],
        },
        {
            urls: [
                "stun:global.stun.twilio.com:3478?transport=udp",
            ],
        },
    ],
    iceCandidatePoolSize: 10,
});
```

Creating offer (A):

```
peer.onnegotiationneeded = async () => {
    offer = await peer.createOffer();
    await peer.setLocalDescription(offer);
};
```

Collecting ice candidates (A):

```
peer.onicecandidate = (evt) => {
    if (evt.candidate) {
        iceCandidates.push(evt.candidate);
    } else {
        // send offer and iceCandidates to B through signaling server
        // this part is working perfectly
    }
};
```

Creating answer and populating ice candidates (B):

```
await peer.setRemoteDescription(offer);

let answer = await this._peer.createAnswer();
await peer.setLocalDescription(answer);

// send answer back to A through signaling server

for (let candidate of sigData.iceCandidates) {
    await peer.addIceCandidate(candidate);
}
```

On answer from B through signaling server (A):

```
await peer.setRemoteDescription(answer);
```

Detect connection state change (A and B):

```
peer.onconnectionstatechange = () => {
    console.log("state changed")
    console.log(peer.connectionState);
}
```

Also note that there were two occasions where it connected successfully, but I am yet to see it work again.

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention I am also creating a data channel (the `onicecandidate` event doesn't seem to call without this). This is called immediately after the `RTCPeerConnection` is constructed and any event handlers have been attached.

```
let channel = peer.createDataChannel("...", {
    id: ...,
    ordered: true,
});
```

**EDIT 2**: As [@jib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/918910/jib) suggested, I am now also gathering ice candidates in B and sending them back to A to add. However, the exact same problem persists.

**EDIT 3**: It seems to connect the first time I hard reload the webpage for A and the webpage for B. Connection stops working again until I do another hard reload. Does anyone have any ideas why this is the case? At least I should be able to continue development for the time being until I can figure out this issue.

**EDIT 4**: I removed the `iceServers` I was using and left the `RTCPeerConnection` constructor blank. Somehow it is much more reliable now. But I am yet to get a successful connection on iOS Safari!

Comment: You're only gathering ICE candidates on one side. Also, you're caching them which defeats the whole purpose of Trickle ICE. Instead, signal them asap. In general you want A and B to have the same code, not different code.

Comment: @jib I've tried gathering ice candidates in B and sending them back to A, where A then calls `addIceCandidate`, with no luck still.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally! After a few weeks I have figured out the issue, which wasn't apparent in the code I included in my question, but may still be useful for anyone who is having similar problems.

I assumed that the ice gathering was being completed *after* the `onnegotiationneeded` event fired and the offer/answer was created.

Because of this incorrect assumption, I was signaling the offer/answer along with the ice candidates at this stage, but very frequently (always in iOS Safari from my experience) the offer/answer was not yet created at this point.

I solved this by creating two promises for a) the completion of ice candidate gathering, and b) the creation of the offer/answer. I used `Promise.all` on the two promises, and when they both completed, I sent the ice candidates and offer/answer down through the signaling server all at once.

This works, but of course in the future I should "trickle" this information, by sending bits and pieces as they come, instead of waiting for everything to fully complete. But I'll worry about that in the future, since at the moment I am using HTTP requests, and it is too much hassle.

**EDIT**: My connection is still always stuck when `iceServers` are included, so I've created a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62772851/webrtc-stuck-in-connecting-state-when-ice-servers-are-included). But local connections when no `iceServers` are included are now 100% fully reliable :)

Comment: Basically, my signaling system sends down the offer/answer and ice candidates at the same time in a single message. I was sending this message once the offer/answer was created before assuring that the ice candidates had been fully gathered at this point. In my situation I needed to ensure both the ice candidates were gathered and the offer/answer was generated before sending them both through my signaling system. If you are sending them separately then this is likely not the issue for you.

Answer (score 2):

Open [this](https://jsfiddle.net/jib1/2yLakm60) in two browser windows and hit the `Connect` button in one of them. This is the code:

```
const pc = new RTCPeerConnection();

call.onclick = async () => {
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video:true,audio:true})
  video.srcObject = stream;
  for (const track of stream.getTracks()) {
    pc.addTrack(track, stream);
  }
};

pc.ontrack = ({streams}) => video.srcObject = streams[0];
pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = () => console.log(pc.iceConnectionState);
pc.onicecandidate = ({candidate}) => sc.send({candidate});
pc.onnegotiationneeded = async () => {
  await pc.setLocalDescription(await pc.createOffer());
  sc.send({sdp: pc.localDescription});
}

const sc = new localSocket(); // localStorage signaling hack
sc.onmessage = async ({data: {sdp, candidate}}) => {
  if (sdp) {
    await pc.setRemoteDescription(sdp);
    if (sdp.type == "offer") {
      await pc.setLocalDescription(await pc.createAnswer());
      sc.send({sdp: pc.localDescription});
    }
  } else if (candidate) await pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);
}
```

This is the same source for A and B. Replace the `localSocket` hack with your preferred signaling channel (e.g. websocket).

Don't cache ICE candidates since that defeats the purpose of Trickle ICE. It may appear fast locally, but in real networks ICE may take time.

In fact, sending candidates is meaningless if you delay sending the offer/answer until all local candidates have been gathered, since candidates are already embedded in the offer/answer (`pc.localDescription`) at that point.

Comment: The call button didn't work for me, probably because I don't have a camera. But I managed to get it working by removing my custom `iceServers` and leaving the `RTCPeerConnection` constructor blank like you have above. Do you have any idea why the `iceServers` I used weren't working? I heard that if I leave the `iceServers` blank, the browser might not have any defaults, so I don't want to take that risk.

Comment: Also, if I attach an empty `ondatachannel` event to B, suddenly the connection stops working.